# Is there a way to start a program minimized with VBScript using WScript.Shell?

Tags: windows, command-line, vbscript, command-line-arguments

Here is some example code I have right now to launch an app:

```
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")     
objShell.Run """C:\Program Files\Handbrake\HandBrakeCLI.exe"""
```

I tried the following to launch the app minimized but it didn't work. I'm assuming this only works from a normal command prompt?

```
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")     
objShell.Run "start /MIN ""C:\Program Files\Handbrake\HandBrakeCLI.exe"""
```

I've also tried launching a shortcut (which just gave a null error and the script couldn't run) as well as trying to do a `sendkeys` to minimize it which didn't work at all.

This is from a VBScript running via cscript.exe by the way.

Does anyone know how I can start this app minimized within VBScript?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and use the second parameter of the .Run method.

Evidence:

```
set s = createobject("WScript.Shell")
s.run "notepad", 2
```

starts Notepad minimized.